# session_decode() makes me logged in also if I didn't login

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a php blog linked to an ecommerce developped with Code Igniter. I can login both in the blog or in the ecommerce with the same credentials, and if I log in I am logged both on the blog and on the ecommerce part.

In the blog, in the config.php file there is:

```
    // Check connection
$sql = "SELECT `data` FROM `ci_sessions` WHERE id="."'".$_COOKIE['ci_session']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$first_arr = '';
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $first_arr = explode(';',$row['data']);
    }

$res = '';
foreach($first_arr as $v){
    if (strpos($v, 'customer_id') !== false) {
        $res = explode('|',$v);
    }
}
$conn->close();

$_SESSION['customer_id'] = session_decode($res[1]);
}
else{
    $_SESSION['customer_id'] = '';
}
if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){
    $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $_SESSION['login_id'];
}
```

I previously used *unserialize()* function instead *session_decode()*, but I wasn't able to login in the blog part.
I fix this with the *session_decode()* function, but now the scenario is: when I am on the blog (not logged) and I go on the ecommerce I am rightly redirected on the login page, but if I don't login and I come back to the previous page I see the blog page like I'm logged in! 
I tried to cancel cache or using an anonymous session, but this happens always!
What could be the problem?

Comment: Seems you are using the same session variables on both systems

Comment: where is this session created $_SESSION['login_id']

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: what is in $_COOKIE['ci_session'] when you have this error and what is returned from table ci_sessions?

Comment: I have a cookie session in it when i come back!